# How does one use cv::boxPoints(RotatedRect box, OutputArray points)

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried the following:

```
cv::RotatedRect minRect = cv::minAreaRect(contour);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> boxPts;
cv::boxPoints(minRect, boxPts);
```

The boxPoints function does not seem to like the vector of Point2f.  What kind of OutputArray does it want?

Comment: what is the contour here ? Like either vetor of vector or matrix

Answer (score 6):

One can also use [RotatedRect.points](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html#a69d648b086f26dbce0029facae9bfb2d) which works with `Point2f[]` as follow:

```cpp
RotatedRect minRect = minAreaRect(contour);
vector<Point2f> boxPts(4);
minRect.points(boxPts.data());
```

Comment: Here contour is vector<vector<Point>> or matrix

Comment: If I remember correctly it is the result if findCotours

Answer (score 3):

Give a `Mat` as **OutputArray**.

```
RotatedRect minRect = minAreaRect(contour);
Mat boxPts;
boxPoints(minRect, boxPts);
cout << boxPts.size() << endl;
cout << "boxPts " << endl << " " << boxPts << endl;
```

The order of the box points: **bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right**

Answer (score 2):

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)

center = rect[0]
size = rect[1]
angle = rect[2]
```

`rect` is array of length 3 which consists of center, size and angle of contour which is of rectangular shape in my project.
`cv2.boxPoints(rect)` computes the vertices of polygon and returns ndarray of vertices of polygon.

**Illustration of below questions:**

How it stores coordinates in array?

How to know the position of each vertices in `box` array?
[image: Arrangement of Coordinates of BOX ndarray]

Vertex [x, y] i.e `box[3]` in our image, having maximum value of y-coordinates (bottom point) among all of the coordinates of Vertices of Polygon, will be last element of `box numpy array.

`box[0]` i.e first element of `box` array is the vertex point that is joined first with point `box[3]` in clockwise direction.

`box[1]`is the vertex point that is joined first with point `box[0]` in clockwise direction and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `cv::boxPoints()` needs a `cv::Mat` as the `OutputArray`.

The rows are the 4 points and the two columns are x and y.